# How can I iterate on XML elements from an XML using XMLReader and bypass whitespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Let say you have an XML like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class HashCode="307960707">
  <Person>
    <Class HashCode="-2020100801">
      <FullName>
        <FirstName>Dan</FirstName>
        <LastName>K</LastName>
      </FullName>
    </Class>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Class HashCode="-439631396">
      <Address>
        <Street>abc</Street>
        <City>new york</City>
        <ZipCode>30500</ZipCode>
        <PhoneNumber>1245</PhoneNumber>
      </Address>
    </Class>
    <Class HashCode="-1436395737">
      <Person>
        <Class HashCode="-1303968324">
          <FullName>
            <FirstName>katty</FirstName>
            <LastName>G</LastName>
          </FullName>
        </Class>
        <Age>18</Age>
        <Class HashCode="-439631396">
          <Address />
        </Class>
        <Class HashCode="307960707">
          <Person />
        </Class>
      </Person>
    </Class>
```

I want to be able to iterate only elements with `XMLReader` in the order they appear, which means class->Person-> class->FullName ,etc..
I was trying to navigate with methods like `XMLReader.ReadStartElement()` and it didn't work especially when I read a whitespaces like `"\n"` which appears to be an element also. :/
I was trying to bypass that whitespace with method `XMLReader.Read()` with no success.

Please help me understand how should I navigate that way.

Comment: Your XML is not valid. Names cannot contain spaces, and `</>` is not a valid end tag.

Comment: Okay this was for illustration, only , the </> don't exist,and also whitespaces between elements such as Dan don't exist

Comment: This is not an output from my program, my original XML is similar to this apart from what I mentioned above

Comment: I meant `<Zip Code/>` is not valid.

Comment: Okay, I wrote it just to simplify
I don't have two words in reality with a whitespace between them :)
I will edit it now again
The whitespace I see is "\n" after `<Class>` for example

Comment: We can't help you if we have to guess what the problem is. Please always post examples which actually fail in the way your real code does.

Comment: okay got it will post some "real" output

Comment: Doesn't WhitespaceHandling help you? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.whitespacehandling.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I was about to warn you this is more complicated example but this is my real xml output, hope that it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlReader` constructor has an overload that takes an `XmlReaderSettings` object.  The `XmlReaderSettings` object has an `IgnoreWhitespace` property.

In order to read only the next elements you can implement an extension method on XmlReader.

Here's an example:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool ReadNextElement(this XmlReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's a little console application that will demonstrate this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;
        settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;

        var reader = XmlReader.Create("XMLFile1.xml", settings);
        while (reader.ReadNextElement())
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds good will check this now, anyway is it possible to iterate between elements using some method like `ReadStartElement()`

Comment: I just wanted to add that `ReadStartElement(`) does the iteration between elements when whitspaces are being ignored.